# React - target values from input with component class

Tags: reactjs, events, state

I am currently working on a project using `Class Components` and unable to use regular `Functional Component Hooks`.

Basically I have a component with an `axios` get request from my back-end.
What I want to do is target the input value and save it into a variable, however, I am uncertain on how to do it without hooks.

**This is my component:**

```
interface RouteParam {
    price: any;
}

interface CouponByPrice extends RouteComponentProps<RouteParam> { 

}

interface CouponDetailState {
    coupons: CouponModel[];
    price: any;
}

class GetCouponByPrice extends Component<CouponByPrice, CouponDetailState> {

    public constructor(props: CouponByPrice) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coupons: null,
            price: '150'
           
        };
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: globals.urls.customerCouponsByPrice,
                params: { price: this.state.price },
              
            })
            store.dispatch(couponsAction(response.data));
            this.setState({ coupons: response.data });
        } catch (err) {
            notify.error(err);
        }
    }

    textHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({price: event.target.value})
            
    }
    
    public render(): JSX.Element {

        return (
            <div className="CatDetails Box">
                {!this.state.coupons && <EmptyView msg="No Coupons for that price" />}
                {this.state.coupons && (
                    <>
                        <div className="top">
                            <h1>Coupon By Maximum price</h1>
                        </div>/
                        <form>
                            <label>
                                Add Price:
                                <input onChange={this.textHandler} type="number" name="price" />
                            </label>
                            
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                        <div className="card">
                            <Box m={4} pt={4} >
                                <Grid container spacing={6}
                                    direction="row"
                                    justifyContent="space-evenly"
                                    alignItems="center"
                                    style={{ minHeight: '80vh' }}
                                >
                                    {
                                        this.state.coupons.map(c => (
                                            <Grid item xs={6} sm={4} >
                                                <Card2 key={c.id} coupon={c} />
                                            </Grid>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </Grid>
                            </Box>
                        </div>

                        <br />
                       
                        <br />
                        <NavLink to="/home">Back</NavLink>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GetCouponByPrice;
```

I was trying to setState of `price` but it doesn't work properly.
What would be best practice for this case.

Still new to this.

Comment: "best practice" is opinionated, "it doesn't work properly." is ambiguous, how we suppose to know how it should work? Please make your question more precise and clearer, adding a codesandbox with reproducible example ensures high answering rate. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I guess you using redux, you should follow its docs and `connect` the component to redux store. https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Answer (score 0):

you can use componentDidUpdate to make your call after the state price change.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.pokemons !== this.state.pokemons) {
    console.log('pokemons state has changed.')
  }
}
```